# Process returned 0 (0x0) python

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, scripting

**I'm learning Python and I wanted to create a simple menu with inputting a number.
When I run the script my console just gives me this error. Any tips on how to fix this ?
I'm coding this in atom with. It ran before I added the menu() and just had it as a normal print() statement. But I want to add more banners and stuff down the road and just think calling a function is prettier in the code than having print statements everywhere.**

```
Process returned 0 (0x0)        execution time : 0.060 s Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Here is my code =)**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Imports
import os
from time import sleep


#Definitions


def menu():
    print('''{0}

    _________________________________________________________________________________
                                {1}
                                    |    [MAIN MENUE]       |
                                    |    [1] Option 1       |
                                    |    [2] Option 2       |
                                    |    [3] Option 3       |
                                    |    [4] Option 4       | {0}
    _________________________________________________________________________________

    '''.format(PURPLE, BLUE))


clear = lambda: os.system('cls') #on Windows System

PURPLE = '\033[95m'
BLUE = '\033[94m'
GREEN = '\033[92m'
OCRA = '\033[93m'
RED = '\033[91m'
ENDC = '\033[0m'
BOLD = '\033[1m'
UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'


#Start of Menu
def mainMenu():

    while True:
        try:

            menu()

            selection = input('{0}[>]Please input your module of choice:  '.format(BLUE))


            if selection == '1':
                print("{0}[+] You have chosen module 1".format(PURPLE))
                sleep(1.5)


            elif selection == '2':
                print("{0}[+] You have chosen module 2".format(PURPLE))
                sleep(1.5)


            elif selection == '3':
                print("{0}[+] You have chosen module 3".format(PURPLE))
                sleep(1.5)


            elif selection == '4':
                print("{0}[+] You have chosen module 4".format(PURPLE))
                sleep(1.5)


            else:
                print("{0}[-] Whoopsie, this module does not exist, try another".format(RED))
                sleep(1.5)
                clear()
                mainMenu()
        except ValueError:




                os.system("pause")
```

Answer (score 1):

You never call mainMenu, so your code is doing almost nothing and return 0 (mean no error).

You should add a call to the mainMenu function in your code

```
mainMenu()
```